# WebSphere Liberty Profile OIDC Client URL

Tags: oauth, websphere-liberty, openid-connect

I am trying to use the WebSphere Liberty Profile OIDC Client feature. I have the feature installed and configured, but I am confused about what URL I should be using to connect to it. In the WLP Knowledge Center, it shows an example like this:

```
https://server.example.com:443/oidc/endpoint/PROVIDER_NAME/authorize
```

But when my WLP server comes up, I see the following URL in the log:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost              I addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module OpenID Connect Client Redirect Servlet has been bound to default_host.
com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ibm669-r9v0dvb:11080/oidcclient/
```

I don't know whether to use 'oidcclient' (probably) or 'oidc'. I also don't know what to put as the PROVIDER_NAME. I tried using the ID of my OIDCClient:

```
<openidConnectClient id="oidcRP"
                     clientId="${oauth.client.id}"
                     clientSecret="${oauth.client.secret}"
                     authorizationEndpointUrl="${oauth.authorize.endpoint}"
                     tokenEndpointUrl="${oauth.token.endpoint}"
                     httpsRequired="false"
                     redirectToRPHostAndPort="https://myhost.com:443">
```

I tried connecting with this, but it's not finding it:

```
http://ibm669-r9v0dvb:11080/oidcclient/endpoint/oidcRP/authorize?scope=openid&response_type=code&client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=https://myhost.com:443

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor  W handleRequest SRVE0190E: File not found: /endpoint/oidcRP/authorize
```

Can anyone tell me what URL I should be using to connect to the client?

Answer (score 0):

The Liberty openidConnectClient feature enables Liberty as a client to openid connect provider. The configuration parameters inside openidConnectClient are information about openidConnectProvider, for example, the openidConnect provider's authorization endpoint and token endpoint.
What is your openid connect provider? Liberty also can be configured as openid Connect provider. If you also want to use Liberty as openid connect provider, you can create another Liberty instance and enable openidConnectProvider feature.

Comment: Thanks, Chunlong. I do no want to use WLP as the provider, we already have another service to be the provider. But I can't help but think that the URL I need to connect to my OIDC Client in WLP has to come from a well-known URL PATH in the client plus my config parms shown in my original question. I just need to know what URL I need to connect to the client.

Comment: Never mind. I see now that the URL that is being displayed in the WLP log is the redirect URI.